# Prove Combinatorical and Algebrical $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\mathbb{n}$ ${2n+1 \choose k}$ = $2^{2n}$

Tags: combinatorics

stuck at this question.
My friend told me to use Newton's Binominal formula but I don't understand how -_-

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\mathbb{n}$ ${2n+1 \choose k}$ = $2^{2n}$

Also , in the combinatorical way I know that $2^{2n}$ is the amount of subsets that exist in a set with 2n elements.
but I don't understand why its equal to the Left-hand-side?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Expand $(1+1)^{2n}$ using the binomial expansion.

Comment: Rather, expand $(1+1)^{2n+1}$ using Binomial Theorem, then observe that $\binom nk = \binom n {n-k}$

Comment: Lol what , I was searching and found only similar question not the link you sent. Thank you.

Comment: Check the Binomial properties..

Answer (score 1):

Say we have $2n+1$ people. Choose majority of these (can be everyone) to be red team and the rest will be blue team. The number of people in blue team is $k=0,...,n$. The number of possible team assignment is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{2n+1}{k}}
$$

Here is another way, first divide the people into two groups. Then the group with more people will be red team. The number of ways to divide $2n+1$ people into two groups is

$$
2^{2n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

W.K.T $${n \choose r} = {n \choose n-r}$$

So, $$ {2n+1 \choose 0} = {2n+1 \choose 2n+1}$$
$${2n+1 \choose 1} = {2n+1 \choose 2n}$$
$${2n+1 \choose 2} = {2n+1 \choose 2n-1}$$
and so on until
$${2n+1 \choose n} = {2n+1 \choose n+1}$$
$${2n+1 \choose n+1} = {2n+1 \choose n}$$

Hence,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {2n+1 \choose k} = \sum_{k=n+1}^ \left(2n+1\right) {2n+1 \choose k} =  
 1/2\sum_{k=0}^ \left(2n+1\right) {2n+1 \choose k}$$

$$ (1+x)^ {2n+1} = C_0 + C_1 X + C_2 X^2 +.... + C_\left(2n+1\right) x^ {2n+1} $$ from binomial expansion

So,
$$ 2^ \left(2n+1\right) = \sum_{k=0}^ \left(2n+1\right) {2n+1 \choose k}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {2n+1 \choose k} =  1/2\sum_{k=0}^ \left(2n+1\right) {2n+1 \choose k} = 1/2* 2^ \left(2n+1\right) = 2^{2n} $$